# PSEXEC will not open .lnk files

Tags: cmd, psexec, lnk

I am having an issue with PSEXEC to open .lnk files. It opens up but then closes. Can anyone help?

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (C:\_\2_Launch_Program\computers.txt) do (
start "%%i" C:\_\PStools\psexec \\%%i -u [Username] -p [password] -i 
cmd.exe /c START c:\Filename.lnk
)
```

Comment: You don't need `START` to open a .lnk shortcut.

Comment: @eryksun so the code should look like this?


    'cmd.exe /c c:\Filename.lnk'

Comment: @eryksun when i do not use START the cmd window will not close even though removing the START will open the .lnk file. Any idea why the cmd window stays open on the machine executing the script to remote computers?

Comment: What's the target of Filename.lnk?

Comment: @eryksun the target is:  "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" -k https://[internal URL]

Comment: I believe this has happened once i removed the START the DO loop is not sure how to end, therefore leaving the PSEXEC CMD windows open on my screen. Do you know how i can resolve this?